# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other type

Tags: object, dbnull

Cannot figure out what is wrong here. Any thoughts?

```
for( int j = i + 1; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                if (dt.Rows[j]["DUPE"] == "X") { continue; }
                if (dt.Rows[i][0].ToString().Trim()==dt.Rows[j][0].ToString().Trim())
                {
                    dt.Rows[i]["On Hand"] = Convert.ToInt64(dt.Rows[i]["On Hand"]) + Convert.ToInt64(dt.Rows[j]["On Hand"]);
                    dt.Rows[j]["DUPE"] = "X";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your database is returning null for one of the "On Hand" columns.  If this is expected, you need to check the value of the "On Hand" column against DBNull.Value before converting.

Comment: I am actually counting the duplicate rows in an excel file and having it output to a .csv file. I am wanting to compute the duplicates, combine those rows and the counts in them, and then output the new file.